# Configure Solaris to write out a core image of an abnormally terminated telnet and man process

Tags: solaris, core-dump

What is the easiest way to configure Solaris to write out a core image of an abnormally terminated telnet and man process?

Answer (score 2):

Use [coreadm(1m)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29031/coreadm-1m.html) to configure global core dumps to a central directory such as `/var/cores`.

Comment: so would that command be like
coreadm -g /var/cores/

Comment: @jay Use something like `coreadm -e global -G all -g /var/cores/%f.%p.%u.%n`